# calculation of depth buffer values

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer

i searched for the answer but i still didn't find a understandable answer, so i'm asking how to calculate the value at depth buffer.

In
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering
here is the formula as image:
[image]

and here it is written by me:
z' = (2^d -1 ) * ((far + near)/(2 * (far - near) + (1 / z) * (-far * near) / (far - near) + 1/2)
when d is the depth of the z-buffer (24 bits at my case)
and z is the z value of the vertex.

i wrote a simple code and tried to run it and read the depth buffer value and calculate it, but i receive deifferent answers.

my code example:

```
/* init */
#define CUBE_SIDE_SIZE 0.25
glViewport(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); 
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
/* draw */
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(-CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, -CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, -CUBE_SIDE_SIZE);
glVertex3f(-CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, -CUBE_SIDE_SIZE);
glVertex3f(CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, -CUBE_SIDE_SIZE);
glVertex3f(CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, -CUBE_SIDE_SIZE, -CUBE_SIDE_SIZE);
glEnd();
```

I read from the depth buffer 0.375 value.
How can i get this value by calculation?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the depth buffer values? Btw: Dont use the deprecated methods of OpenGL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nearValue is -1, farValue is +1. Your cube is at -0.25. So the distance from the near plane is 0.75. The z values are scaled to the depth range, which defaults to [0,1]. Since farValue-nearValue = 2, that means the depth value is 0.75/2 = 0.375.

Also, you posted a formula for perspective projection, but you use an orthographic projection.

Comment: thanks, but what about whole the formula above? don't i need the depth of the Z-buffer bits?

Comment: No, you don't need that. If you want to understand OpenGL's transformations, I would suggest looking at [9.011 How are coordinates transformed? What are the different coordinate spaces?](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm). An even better resource is the OpenGL specification itself. You should stick to OpenGL-specific resources and ignore Wikipedia.

Comment: correct me if i wrong, but by this calculation:<br> Z-buffer value = (z - nearValue) / (farValue - nearValue)<br> The Z-buffer is supposet to be linear and it's not.<BR> What am i missing?

Comment: For orthographic projections the z-buffer is linear indeed. For perspective projections it's not, because of the perspective divide which happens when clip coordinates are transformed into normalized device coordinates. In NDC, the z-values are in the range [-1,1], and they are then linearly mapped to the range [n,f], where n and f are set with `glDepthRange(n,f)`, which defaults to 0 and 1. Those values are not to be confused with the near/far values from the perspective projection.